# Faster and precise way to count lines other than wc -l

Tags: linux, bash, count, lines, wc

Usually I use `wc -l` to count the lines of a file. However for a file with 5*10^7 lines, I get only 10^7 as an answer. 
I've tried everything proposed here here: 
[How to count lines in a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137094/how-to-count-lines-in-a-document)
But it takes to much time than `wc -l`.

Is there any other option?

Comment: where did you get the file, is there DOS/UNIX line break problem?

Comment: `awk 'END {print NR}'`

Comment: @Jidder i think awk has some limit.

Comment: @Avinash Raj Is there , i know there are limits for NF and characters per record but ive never had a problem with NR. I just check on a million line file and it worked. Never had one 50 millions line before though.

Comment: @Kent. The file was created during a MD (molecular dynamics) simulations. I'm almost sure that there is no problem in the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Count how many lines in large files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12716570/1983854) (not marking it as so, because would close it automatically). I've doing some checkings and `wc -l` is way faster than other alternatives. With 10^7 lines, it took `0m0.089s`, while `awk's END{}` was 2nd with `0m0.404s`. Then `sed` with `0m1.101s` and finally `nl` with more than 3s.

Comment: You should file a bug with GNU Coreutils.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone serious about speed line counting can just create their own implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE (1024 * 16)
char BUFFER[BUFFER_SIZE];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    unsigned int lines = 0;
    int fd, r;

    if (argc > 1) {
        char* file = argv[1];
        if ((fd = open(file, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file \"%s\".\n", file);
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        fd = fileno(stdin);
    }

    while ((r = read(fd, BUFFER, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
        char* p = BUFFER;
        while ((p = memchr(p, '\n', (BUFFER + r) - p))) {
            ++p;
            ++lines;
        }
    }

    close(fd);

    if (r == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Read error.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%d\n", lines);

    return 0;
}
```

Usage

```
a < input
... | a
a file
```

Example:

```
# time ./wc temp.txt
10000000

real    0m0.115s
user    0m0.102s
sys     0m0.014s

# time wc -l temp.txt
10000000 temp.txt

real    0m0.120s
user    0m0.103s
sys     0m0.016s
```

*****   Code compiled with `-O3` natively on a system with AVX and SSE4.2 using GCC 4.8.2.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `sed`

```
sed -n '$=' file
```

The `=` says to print the line number, and the dollar says to only do it on the last line. The `-n` says not to do too much else.

Or here's a way in Perl, save this as `wc.pl` and do `chmod +x wc.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

    my $filename = <@ARGV>;
    my $lines = 0;
    my $buffer;
    open(FILE, $filename) or die "ERROR: Can not open file: $!";
    while (sysread FILE, $buffer, 65536) {
        $lines += ($buffer =~ tr/\n//);
    }
    close FILE;
    print "$lines\n";
```

Run it like this:

```
wc.pl yourfile
```

Basically it reads your file in in chunks of 64kB at a time and then takes advantage of the fact that `tr` returns the number of substitutions it has made after asking it to delete all newlines.

Comment: I know that sounds weird, but using this command I have simply no output. I tried for a very small file (7 lines) and it works.

Comment: I have had a go in Perl too, please have another look.

Answer (score 1):

Try with nl and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the line count using `awk` as well like below

```
awk 'END {print NR}' names.txt
```

(OR) Using `while .. do .. done` bash loop construct like

```
CNT=0; while read -r LINE; do (( CNT++ )); done < names.txt; echo $CNT
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you open the file, but probably reading it from STDIN instead would get the fix:

```
wc -l < file
```