# Ubuntu terminal - using gnu parallel to read lines in all files in folder

Tags: multithreading, bash, ubuntu, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I am Trying to count the lines in all the files in a very large folder under Ubuntu.

The files are .gz files and I use

```
zcat * | wc -l
```

to count all the lines in all the files, and it's slow!

I want to use multi core computing for this task and found [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Count-the-differences-between-all-files-in-a-dir)
about Gnu parallel,

I tried to use this bash command:

```
parallel zcat * | parallel --pipe wc -l
```

and the cores are not all working 
I found that the job starting might cause major overhead and tried using batching with

```
parallel -X zcat * | parallel --pipe -X wc -l
```

without improvenemt,

how can I use all the cores to count the lines in all the files in a folder given they are all .gz files and need to be decompresses before counting the rows (don't need to keep them uncompressed after)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about parallel, though from this link, https://drjohnstechtalk.com/blog/2011/06/gnu-parallel-really-helps-with-zcat/, you should use a command more like l `ls *gz|time parallel -k "zcat {}" | wc -l`

Comment: thanks. seems to utilize the cores better, need to check the result, could you explain a bit more about the syntax and create an answer?

Comment: Basically `parallel` expects an input, so you list files, pipe it to parallel, ask parallel to keep the order, which might not be necessary in this case (`-k`), use parallel with zcat on one line of the list `"zcat {}"` and then pipe the whole to `wc`. By the way there is a typo in the command above, the `time` command should be removed. I will write a more explicit answer tonight (after some testing on my side) if no one beats me to it!

Comment: Thanks! waiting for it.

Comment: finished testing it now, it gave a total number of lines in all the files, this is not what i needed, i needed a list of the number of lines in each file, i obtained it based on you answer and using ls dest/* |time parallel -k "zcat {} | wc -l"

Comment: check the post by by Nicholas Sushkin here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716570/count-lines-in-large-files

Comment: What do you mean by a *"large folder"*? Do you mean there are millions of files? Or that there are a few files each many hundred GB?

Comment: arount 150k files that are long files (8mb when .gz and around 150mb when decompressed) a part of the issue is that the list is too long for ls

Comment: Is this on a normal, single spinning disk, or some type of SSD that can sustain multiple readers? I presume your files are 8MB (8 megabytes) rather than 8mb (8 millibits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 150,000 files, you will likely get problems with *"argument list too long"*. You can avoid that like this:

```
find . -name \*gz -maxdepth 1 -print0 | parallel -0 ...
```

If you want the name beside the line count, you will have to `echo` it yourself, since your `wc` process will only be reading from its `stdin` and won't know the filename:

```
find ... | parallel -0 'echo {} $(zcat {} | wc -l)'
```

Next, we come to efficiency and it will depend on what your disks are capable of. Maybe try with `parallel -j2` then `parallel -j4` and see what works on your system.

---

As Ole helpfully points out in the comments, you can avoid having to output the name of the file whose lines are being counted by using **GNU Parallel**'s `--tag` option to tag output line, so this is even more efficient:

```
find ... | parallel -0 --tag 'zcat {} | wc -l'
```

Comment: Also look at --tag.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the command you are looking for is:

```
ls *gz | parallel 'zcat {} | wc -l'
```

What it does is:

- `ls *gz`list all gz files on stdout
- Pipe it to `parallel`
- Spawn subshells with `parallel`
- Run in said subshells the command inside quotes `'zcat {} | wc -l'`

About the '{}', according to the manual:

> This replacement string will be replaced by a full line read from the input source

So each line piped to parallel get fed to zcat.

Of course this is basic, I assume it could be tuned, [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) and examples might help